# Stack CSS elements horizontally

Tags: html, css

I would like to know if there is a way to make elements of container stack vertically without providing width. I mean I have container with for example 30 images (with width of 30px) and I would like to show them all horizontally without specyfing container width since I don't know how many items will I have there. So basically I would like to display elements in row without specyfing width of container and without breaking them to next row when they don't have more space in current one. I hope I explained it well.

Comment: Did you try using - float:left;

Comment: or `display: inline-block;`? Could you please provide us with the necessary code or a jsfiddle?

Comment: Obviously I am not interested in simple float:left or inline-block. What I want is to wrap elements horizontally instead of vertically. So when I have 30 elements 30px wide each and container with width of 100px I still want to show all of this elements in single line without wrapping them to next line after every 3 elements.

Answer (score 2):

Float the images left so they stack in a row. Also float the wrapper left so it contains the contents inside it (this will automatically expand as the number of items inside expands without a need for a width)

```
<style>
    #wrapper{
        float:left;
    }

    #wrapper li{
        float:left;
        background:black;
        width:30px;
        height: 30px;
        margin:0 10px 0 0;
    }
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c4NZX/

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works as long as the `li`s fit in 100% of the container.  After that they will wrap.  You can see that behavior when you add 20 `li`s to your fiddle. It is my believe the OP wants to see some horizontal scrolling when that happens.

Comment: I want elements to not wrap vertically. So even if there is no more space in current row I still want to show them in this one row. I would like to create scrolling horizontal list of thumbs, but I dont know how many of them I will get. Maybe this will give you a better idea of what I want.